# Convert C string to Go string without CGO

Tags: c, go, cgo

I'm using the Go Windows syscall libraries to get data out of a function in a DLL.  This all works great, but I can't figure out a way to convert a LPCTSTR (pointer to C String) into a proper Go string *without using CGO*.

I'd like to avoid CGO if at all possible, because the two options for CGO code on Windows (cross-compiling, and installing gcc on windows) are still fairly complex.

Comment: I don't *think* there's an easy way other than CGO without doing something hacky. You don't need gcc for CGO, you can set CGO's compiler by setting the env var `CC=<desired compiler>`.  I don't know much about windows' c compiler though, or env vars in windows for that matter.

Comment: You can certainly convert the strings, but the problem is that LPCTSTR is conditionally a typedef for LPCSTR or LPCWSTR. Do you have any way to ensure the type?

Comment: @JimB, yes, I think the type of the string is implied by the function I'm calling that has either an "A" or "W" suffix for the two types of data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an 8 bit string, you can convert the LPCTSTR pointer to a `[]byte` of the proper size, and copy it to a new string or slice.

```
a := (*[1 << 30-1]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(lpctstr))
size := bytes.IndexByte(a[:], 0)
// if you just want a string
// goString := string(a[:size:size])

// if you want a slice pointing to the original memory location without a copy
// goBytes := a[:size:size]

goBytes := make([]byte, size)
copy(goBytes, a)
```

If the LPCTSTR points to an LPCWSTR which contains 16bit unicode characters, you can convert that with the utf16 package.

```
a := (*[1 << 30-1]uint16)(unsafe.Pointer(lpctstr))
size := 0
for ; size < len(a); size++ {
    if a[size] == uint16(0) {
        break
    }
}   
runes := utf16.Decode(a[:size:size])
goString := string(runes)
```

Comment: nice. Why might copy be needed unless you just want a string?

Comment: @Mark: converting it to a string implicitly makes a copy of the bytes. If you return a slice directly from the array, it will point to the original memory location which may or may not be safe to access later.

Comment: why `gostring := a[:size:size]` (question is :size:size).
like what is wrong here: `gostring := a[:size]`

Answer (score 1):

If you can get a pointer to a cstring without CGO, and you can get the length of the string too, then perhaps you should create a byte slice from the cstring first.

```
import (
    "reflect"
    "unsafe"
)

func ToByteSlice() []byte {
    var bytes []byte

    shdr := (*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&bytes))
    shdr.Cap = int(stringlen)
    shdr.Len = int(stringlen)
    shdr.Data = uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(cpointer))

    return bytes
}
```